# Fastest way to append two arrays ( concatenate two arrays) C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the fastest way to append two arrays together
I know it is a simple problem. But I need a very quick way to do it maybe by using a library function

Here is my code below which does it without any library functions

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
       int b[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
       int c[10];

       for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
       {
          c[i] = a[i];   
       }

       for(int i=5; i<10; i++)
       {
          c[i] = b[i-5];   
       }


       for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
       {
          cout << c[i] << endl;  
       }


}
```

what is a more efficient way ?

Comment: I added <algorithm> library because I thought there are functions in it that does this faster. There are none ?

Comment: You're not using any of them.

Comment: Which library you added?

Comment: Why do you think you need a more efficient way?  What you have now takes zero time.

Comment: Thought there was a better more efficient way. also I am learning new functions from this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think your loops are fine. If you want to, you can try if merging them into one loop gives you any speed-up because you only need half the iterations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    c[i] = a[i];
    c[i+5] = b[i];
}
```

But **measure** this, it is by no means guaranteed to be faster. If the arrays always are that small, any difference in performance is highly unlikely.

If you want to use the `<algorithm>` library (which I like to do for readability, but in your case the loops are short enough), you can do it like this:

```
std::copy(a, a+5, c);
std::copy(b, b+5, c+5);
```

It most likely is not faster than the loops, but looks cleaner IMO. When the amount of data gets bigger, it might actually offer a speedup by being implemented in an optimized way, but as always, measure it.

I would stay away from `memcpy` though. It does not work on all types and offers no (or should not offer any) advantage over `std::copy`.

As a last remark, consider replacing the raw C-arrays with the modern [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). One advantage here is that you can just copy it with `=`, plus some neat member functions like `fill` and `size`.

Comment: Your point about `memcpy` having no advantage over `std::copy` is true. The library implementation of `std::copy` may even use `memcpy` or `memmove` when given pointers to scalars. I know MSVC does this.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Specifically the plain loops use an extra useless indirection because of the index, and they don't use loop expansion. The compiler might be smart enough to optimize it despite all that, but `std::copy` *is* optimized.

Comment: Up-vote for the use of pre-increment over post-increment.  Even though any speed boost probably won't be noticed for arrays that small.

Answer (score 3):

I think that for fundamental types it will be more efficient to use standard C function `memcpy` declared in header `<cstring>`

For example

```
#include <cstring>

//,,,

int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int b[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
int c[10];

std::memcpy( c, a, sizeof( a ) );
std::memcpy( c + 5, b, sizeof( b ) );
```

If you want to use standard algorithms then you could write

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::copy_n( b, 5, std::copy_n( a, 5, c ) );
```

Comment: I like it. fewer lines than mine

Comment: Maybe.  But maybe not.

Comment: @Mozein See also the addition to my post.

Comment: This is a good solution. Both memcpy and std::copy are optimized. std::copy even uses the fast memcpy from c.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `<algorithm>` there is `std::copy`. This one-liner relies on the fact that the inner function call returns an iterator (pointer in this case) to where it left off. The outer function call then continues with copying the `b` array.

```
std::copy(b, b+5, std::copy(a, a+5, c));
```

It's still two loops and O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `<algorithm>`. This seems fine to me, works at O(n) complexity just like the below alternative:

```
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      if(i < 5){
          c[i] = a[i];
      }
      else{
          c[i] = b[i-5];   
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be fastest. Use `vector` instead of vanilla `arrays`

```
#include <vector>

   int main()
    {
     vector<T> one;
     vector<T> two;
     //populate the vector

     //This is the fastest it could get.
     one.insert(one.end(), two.begin(), two.end());
     return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are so concerned about the performance of the algorithm you've provided -- which has O(n) complexity -- then I wonder if you have selected the correct algorithm in the first place.  In other words, if you need to get faster than what you're doing, then maybe you're doing the wrong thing in the first place.

That being said, copying two arrays in to a third, disparate array can not perform better than linear complexity.  Complexity, of course, is largely an academic concern.  The thing that really matters is *speed*.  That is, if your definition of "better" means "faster" than an implementation of an O(n*n) algorithm that runs faster than an implementation of an O(n) algorithm is by your definition better.  Make sure the things you're copying are fast to copy.

You've included `<algorithm>`, but you don't use it.  I would suggest that you should.  Not for performance, per se, but for maintainability.  The fact that the Standard guarantees the algorithmic complexity is a benefit, and you have no such guarantee in code you write aside from testing it and being careful when writing it.  So I would prefer:

```
std::merge (std::begin (a), std::end (a), std::begin (b), std::end (b) , std::begin (c));
```

Assuming `a` and `b` are in fact sorted.  Actually, not using a C-style array would be better still.

```
std::vector <int> a;
std::vector <int> b;
std::vector <int> c;
// ...
std::merge (std::begin (a), std::end (a), std::begin (b), std::end (b) , std::begin (c));
```

And to drive the point home about maintainability, note how the actual code (with the `merge`) didn't have to change even tho I changed the types of containers it worked upon.

Comment: I know what linear preformance and O(n) is. I am aware that this is the best case to run such an algorithm. My concern was if there was a better case. and since it is obvious there is none. i would prefer to keep my lines of code short. By using special library functions I am not aware of. Like the one you provided here

Comment: @Mozein:  Do as you will, but if you're arguing that you'd prefer to have hand-rolled loops simply because the `std::merge` line is longer, and because it's new to you, I would argue that's not a compelling reason to hand-roll loops.  If I saw the code you wrote in a code review, I'd shoot it down as unacceptable because 1) it's less maintainable, 2) it's more prone to bugs, 3) you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You would shoot down the code that I wrote at the top ? good, one of the reasons I asked this question is to find a better looking code. since efficiency is not an issue

Comment: @Mozein:  Yes, the code you wrote at the top for the reasons I said in my previous comment.  The Standard Library is your friend.

Comment: John, I have a code interview soon, and I am trying to eliminate writing codes that are not efficient, or does not look good for reasons that you mentioned.  so concern is not only about the algorithm in an interview, but about the style of writing them. I needed a better looking code and I got a lot of them in these answers

Comment: @Mozein:  Forget about *prettiness* as an important attribute of code, or one that an interviewer will care about.  Prettiness *doesn't matter a whit.*  What does matter is that the code is easy to understand, is easy to maintain, runs with acceptable characteristics, and does not take too long to write.  Using Std Lib routines helps keep code short & understandable with known runtime characteristics, and it takes less time to call a function someone else wrote than to write it yourself.  Remember:  code should be written for humans, not computers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. In CINT, but should compile too.

```
...
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
       int b[] = {6,7,8,9,10};
       int c[10];

       memcpy( &c[0], &a, sizeof(a) );
       memcpy( &c[5], &b, sizeof(b) );

       for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
       {
          cout << c[i] << endl;  
       }
...
```

Nice how many answers appeared. This one is ok also for pure C.